# Gradle runFunction - "CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long" - CloudEventsFunction

Tags: java, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a CloudEventsFunction function that I deploy to GCP Cloud Functions, but test on my local device. Lately, I ran into a command line problem with a CloudEventsFunction when running locally. This function is part of a Gradle Project, which imports a few libraries within the project using `implementation project("<library>"`).

Up until now, this would run fine. However, adding one additional `implementation project` line led to the following when ran the function in IntelliJ (I will note that this is not a problem when it is deployed- only when running locally):

`CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long`

Normally, the solution for running, say, a Spring Application, would be to use IntelliJ's "Shorten command Line" options, but that does not appear to be an option when running a Gradle command.

Run command looks like the following:

`runFunction -Prun.functionTarget=<package.className> -Prun.port=12345`

Outline of build.gradle included here. I'll note that under the 'jar' definition, we list a number of dependencies and 'include' lines to package up in the jar, which are left out here for simplicity's sake.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
configurations {
    invoker
}
dependencies {
//
//    implementation project("")  lines go here
//
    // Every function needs this dependency to get the Functions Framework API.
    compileOnly 'com.google.cloud.functions:functions-framework-api:1.0.4'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    implementation group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-core', version: '3.4.24'
    // To run function locally using Functions Framework's local invoker
    invoker 'com.google.cloud.functions.invoker:java-function-invoker:1.2.0'
    // These dependencies are only used by the tests.
    testImplementation 'com.google.cloud.functions:functions-framework-api:1.0.4'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.2.0'
//
//  Additional dependencies listed here
//
}
tasks.withType(Copy).all { duplicatesStrategy 'exclude' }
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
jar {
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {
            (it.isDirectory()) ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    
    //
    // include directories listed here
    //
    
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
// Register a "runFunction" task to run the function locally
tasks.register("runFunction", JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker'
    classpath(configurations.invoker)
    inputs.files(configurations.runtimeClasspath, sourceSets.main.output)
    args(
            '--target', project.findProperty('run.functionTarget') ?: '',
            '--port', project.findProperty('run.port') ?: 8080
    )
    doFirst {
        args('--classpath', files(configurations.runtimeClasspath, sourceSets.main.output).asPath)
    }
}
```

Additionally, here is a snapshot of my run Configurations for this function:
[image: Function Run Configs Snapshot]